# const tempFunc = () =>{ result }, const tempFunc = () = result, What is the difference between the two codes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
export const get_post_api = id => {
  axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
}
```

[image]

```
export const get_post_api = id =>
  axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
```

[image]

The two codes have different response values. {} What's the difference between this?

Answer (score 1):

The second function returns Axios Promise but the first one does not return anything, even though it does make a request. If you change the first one to:

```js
export const get_post_api = id => {
  return axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
}
```

It will be equivalent to:

```js
export const get_post_api = id =>
  axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
```

In the second case, `return` is implied.

Source: [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions)

Comment: I've been thinking about this all day. you are my savior!